# SQL Query Help - Grouping By Sequences of Digits

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, which includes the following columns and data:

```
id     dtime        instance     data      dtype

1     2012-10-22     10000       d        1
2     2012-10-22     10000       d        1
..
7     2012-10-22     10004       d        1
..
15    2012-10-22     10000       @        1
16    2012-10-22     10004       d        1
17    2012-10-22     10000       d        1
```

I want to group sequences of 'd's in the data column, with the '@' at the end of the sequence.

This could have been done by grouping via the instance column, which is an individual stream of data, however there can be multiple sequences within the stream.

I also want to end a sequence if there are no data columns in the same instance for, say, 3 seconds after the last data of that instance and no '@'s have been found within that interval.

I have managed to do exactly this using cursors and while loops, which worked reasonably well for tables with 1000s of rows, however this query will be used on far more rows eventually, and these two methods would take around a minute with a dataset of just 3-5000 rows.

Reading on this website and others, it seems that set-based logic may be the way to go, however I can think of no way to do what I need without some kind of loop on each row that compares it to every other to build the 'sequences'.

If anyone could help, or point me in the direction of something that could, it would be greatly appreciated. :)

I would ideally like the data to be output in the following format:

datacount instance lastdata  dtime

```
20      10000    @      2012-10-22

19      10000    d      2012-10-22

22      10004    @      2012-10-22

20      10022    @      2012-10-22
```

Where (datacount) is a count of the number of rows in a 'sequence' (which is the data leading up to a '@' or 3 second delay), (instance) is the instance ID from the original table, (lastdata) is the last data value in the sequence, (dtime) is the datetime value of the last data value.

Comment: What is the desired output for the data you posted in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add this to the question, I've now edited it and added the required output to the bottom.

Comment: if it takes too long to build the resultset from raw data you can build the resultset just in time using e.g. a trigger

Comment: Could you please make sure the results you posted match the data you posted?  And an explanation of the results, as they don't seem to match your earlier requirements.  While windowing functions might help, they might not be needed here. And @SirRufo - it's best to be careful with maintained aggregates; they can get out-of-sync easily, and, especially in what seems to be a highly-concurrent system, can lock rows/tables to an extent that can cripple an application.

Comment: Sir Rufo: Thanks, yes this was something I had considered doing if the query could not be made more efficient.

Comment: Clockwork-Muse: Apologies for any confusion, I'll add an explanation of the results to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you how to do this for the final '@'.  The time difference follows a similar idea.  The key idea is to get the next '@' after the current row.  For this you need a correlated subquery.  After that, you can do a group by:

```
select groupid, count(*) as NumInSeq, max(dtime) as LastDateTime
from (select t.*,
             (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.id > t.id and t2.data = '@'
             ) as groupid
      from t
     ) t
group by groupid
```

Handling the time sequence is a bit more complicated.  It is something like this:

```
select groupid, count(*) as NumInSeq, max(dtime) as LastDateTime,
       (case when sum(case when data = '@' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then '@' else 'd' end) as FinalData
from (select t.*,
             (select min(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.id > t.id and
                    (t2.data = '@' or UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.dtime) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.dtime) < 3
             ) as groupid
      from t
     ) t
group by groupid
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the query times out before returning anything however I'll try it on a smaller data set and work out what's causing the slowdown.

Comment: Unfortunately, correlated subqueries do not optimize very well.  In other databases, an alternative solution would use window functions, but these are not available in MySQL.  It might help if you have an index on (id, data) and lift the restriction on the time.

Comment: Retried the query on a data set that's ordered better, and it runs in about a quarter of the time the while loop method would take. There are still a few odd results where 1 data row is counted as 17, which I can't understand, but I'll keep working on it. Thanks for your help. :)